# Trying to do a MySQL Sum based on joining results from second table query

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have two tables (Zen Cart).

One table has the order totals, the other has the order dates.

The two tables are linked by a common orders_id.

I want to take a sum of all the order totals within a date range.

OK, while working on this question, I figured out the answer. Not quite sure if it's done right but the numbers are correct. I'll just leave it up in case it's useful for anyone else.

Is my method correct here?

```
select sum(value) from orders_total 
INNER JOIN 
orders
ON
    (orders.orders_id=orders_total.orders_id 
    AND orders.date_purchased between '2008/1/1' AND '2012/1/1' 
    AND orders_total.class='ot_subtotal');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(value) as orders_total
from orders_date od 
inner join orders_total ot on od.orderid= ot.orderid
where date_format(od.date_purchased, "%Y-%m-%d") between ("2013-04-01") and ("2013-11-30")
```

First need to fetch the orderids from the orders_date table to get orderid within specified daterange.. then inner join the orders_total table.